# jquery autocomplete does not shows result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I have input of type text to which I have attached autocomplete:

javascript:

```
$("#descSearchBox").keyup(function(e) {
//$("#ui-id-1").addClass("dropdown-menu").removeClass('ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');

$(".ui-autocomplete").removeClass("ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all")
    .addClass('dropdown-menu');

$.post("/controls/DistControl.php", {
        action: 'descAutocomplete',
        description: $(this).val(),
        myDistribution: $("#cbMyDistributions").is(":checked")
    }, function(data) {

        data = $.parseJSON(data);

        $( "#titleSearchBox" ).val('');
        console.log(data);

        $( "#descSearchBox" ).autocomplete({
            source: data.result.titles,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#titleSearchBox").val(ui.item.label);

                distributionTableUpdate();
            }
        });
    }
);
});
```

and here is php script that sends request back:

```
function descAutocomplete() {
$where['LIKE'] = [ "description" => $_POST['description'] ];

if( $_POST["myDistribution"] === "true" )
    $where["user_id[=]"] = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$dists = DistributionModel::getAll( $where, 10, 0, 'title', 'ASC', [ 'title' ] );

$titles = [];
foreach($dists as $d) {
    $titles[] = $d->get('title');
}

$response = new ResponseModel(ResponseModel::$TYPE_INFO, 'Description Autocomplete', [ 'titles' => $titles ]);
echo $response->encode();
}
```

The thing is I get result back, for example I just type 'e' in search and I get array with 4 elements but it shows nothing or just shows the last one. Why would do so? Why it does not shows all results?

Comment: you getting all the result in backend?

Comment: Yes, I do get results in backend.

Comment: so the problem might be with css.. or what you are getting in "data" that response you are getting?

Comment: {"type":"info","message":"Description Autocomplete","result":{"titles":["7 Zip","8AF","Adobe advertise","AF","angel","fghd","Test Dist"]}}

This is what I get, and it shows Adobe advertise, angel and Test Dist

Comment: you cannot assign source: data.result.titles titles directly try to seperate it with comma or parse and assign with list not the direct arary. refer this http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/how-to-read-and-parse-json-using-jquery.html

Comment: I parsed json before I wrote data.result.titles, and it does work, but it just doesn't shows all results...
Why I shouldn't assign direct array if it says so in example in documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Like

```
$("#name").autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "URL",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {term: request.term},
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item.state,
            id: item.id
          };
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
  }
});
```